# Knockout Mapping Plugin - Capture Array Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, knockout.js

I have a JSON array coming from a REST API.   I am using the Knockout mapping plugin to process the array and load the JSON into preset form values (if a user has added values to the form previously - I have data there to test the Knockout arrays).  The form essentially adds or deletes div blocks with inputs so users can add/delete "work" experiences.

My trouble is with trying to decipher how the plugin maps the arrays.  I am trying to locate a specific value (the id) of a row in the array so I can add it as a variable to tell the API to delete that specific row.  I can get Knockout to explicitly output the row value in the html, but I can't figure out how to capture it otherwise.  In the template "foreach" I have a button that references a "remove:" and that's where I'm stuck in trying to capture the value from the array.

For Example in the HTML:

This outputs the two rows of the "work" object no problem:

```
<span data-bind="text: ko.mapping.toJSON(workModel.work())"></span>

[{"id":"1","schoolID":"2","place":"","position":"Science Teacher","description":"I worked at ASD for 1 year as a Science teacher.","start":"2011","end":"2012","profileID":"91"},{"id":"2","schoolID":"1","place":"American School of Taiwan","position":"Science Guy","description":"I was just another science guy","start":"2008","end":"2011","profileID":"91"}]
```

This outputs the id of the first row and item in the array:

```
<span data-bind="text: ko.mapping.toJSON(workModel.work()[0].id)"></span>
"1"
```

But in the javascript, if you click on the remove button generated by the foreach template...

```
gone = function(work) {

        alert(ko.mapping.toJSON(workModel.work(this).id)); 

     }
```

Gives me this error in Firebug, and then the UI reloads and drops out the template block I just clicked on.

```
Unable to parse bindings. Message: TypeError: workModel.work()[0] is undefined; Bindings value: text: ko.mapping.toJSON(workModel.work()[0].id)
```

Even though, if I replace the above alert with the explicit statement:

```
gone = function(work) {

         alert(ko.mapping.toJSON(workModel.work()[0].id)); 

         }
```

I get the correct value of "1" again.  I know it has to do with the "this" aspect of the code, but I'm not sure what the mapping plugin is doing so that I can capture the specific value from the array...make sense?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going out on a limb here, but I do think it's the this-problem yes. Scoping in Javascript can be a hassle sometimes. Try doing something like this in the scope containing the gone-function:

```
var self = this;
gone = function(work) {
    alert(ko.mapping.toJSON(workModel.work(self).id)); 
}
```

*Disclaimer: I'm not able to test this myself right now, but give it a try :)*

Comment: Sorry tried it and no go.  If I just do a simple 'alert(self.workModel.work().length);' I get the correct value for all of the arrays.  It's only that one value I can't seem to get to.

Comment: I hink you need to post more of your code. Please post more complete markup and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it.  It came from combining different post on Stack Overflow and also from the Knockout forums. I'm sure other folks have more elegant solutions than this, but it works for me.

In the foreach loop on the "Delete" (or whatever button you want to use to capture the value) button I included the following on the data-bind:

```
<a href="" class="btn" data-bind="click: function() { remove($data.id()); }">Remove</a>
```

Then in the javascript I have:

```
var self = this;
var row_id;

self.remove = function(index){
            var row_id = index;
            alert(row_id);

    }
```

The alert returns the row ID of the loaded JSON as I wanted.  The $data.id() could be changed/used to return any mapped element from the loaded JSON.  The row_id is then a global that can be accessed elsewhere as well.